# Extrating Text from PowerPoint Slide

Tags: xml, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint slide built with Office 2010 (and 2007) that I need to extract text from it programatically. I'm guessing that somewhere Office creates a xml file that may have all the text I need.

Is there a way to do this and how would I go bout it?

I've got VS2010, SharePoint Designer 2007 available for tools.

Thanks,

Risho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there's a hard way, a simple and and even simpler way to do this with Linq-to-XML. Note that I am **not** using the Open XML SDK - I'm just using VB.NET with XML Literals and System.IO.Packaging. You can certainly do this in a more complex manner using the SDK, C#, etc. - depends on what your environment/preferences are.

1. **The hard way**: Go through every
   paragraph, and not only pull the
   text, but also pull all the
   formatting (bold, bullet points,
   etc.)
2. **The simple way**: Go through every
   text entry and just pull the text,
   no formatting.
3. **The even simpler way**: Go to each
   slide and just pull all text.

Here's how you would do #2 (the simple way):

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Packaging 'Add reference to WindowsBase for this
Imports <xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
Imports <xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
Imports <xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
Module Module1
    Public Const documentRelationshipType As String = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument"
    Sub Main()
        Dim slide, document As XElement
        Dim pptPackage As Package = Nothing
        Dim slidePart, documentPart As PackagePart
        Dim filePath As String = "C:\Users\Todd\Desktop\yourpresentation.pptx"
        pptPackage = Package.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        Using pptPackage
            Dim documentRelationship As PackageRelationship = pptPackage.GetRelationshipsByType(documentRelationshipType).FirstOrDefault
            Dim documentUri As Uri = PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(New Uri("/", UriKind.Relative), documentRelationship.TargetUri)
            documentPart = pptPackage.GetPart(documentUri)
            document = XElement.Load(New StreamReader(documentPart.GetStream))

            Dim slideList = From e In document.<p:sldIdLst>.<p:sldId>

            For i = 0 To slideList.Count - 1

                Dim slideReference As String = slideList(i).@r:id.ToString
                slidePart = pptPackage.GetPart(PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(documentPart.Uri, documentPart.GetRelationship(slideReference).TargetUri))
                slide = XElement.Load(New StreamReader(slidePart.GetStream))
                Dim rawText = From e In slide...<a:t>

                For Each t In rawText
                    Console.WriteLine(t.Value)
                Next

            Next
        End Using
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. I'm wonderring if would work since the pptx is a compiled file. I tried to open it in Notepad but all get is scrambled data.

Comment: copy your PPTX. then with the copy of it, change the extension from ".pptx" to ".zip". Then unzip it. All of your slides will be in the "ppt" folder inside as XML files (slide1.xml, slide2.xml, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is what I was after!